# How to convert string to object array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string as shown below

```
[{ date: new Date(2015,9,25), NAV: 12},{ date: new Date(2016,9,25), NAV: 22}]
```

how can i convert that to object array using jQuery?

Comment: It does not look like a string

Comment: use JSON.pase(yourArray)

Comment: Is `new Date(2015,9,25)` part of your string? If it is, it will throw error.

Comment: JSON.parse ;) it is

Comment: Its not string its json array but not properly formatted

Comment: a string represent double quotation marks like "imAString"

Comment: @Ajai how have you written above string
`var loremString = "[{ date: new Date(2015,9,25), NAV: 12},{ date: new Date(2016,9,25), NAV: 22}]";`
or
`var loremArray = [{ date: new Date(2015,9,25), NAV: 12},{ date: new Date(2016,9,25), NAV: 22}];`
?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @msagala So by your statement `'imAString'` is not string because it uses `'` and not `"`?

Comment: @Justinas yeah it work too with single quotation marks. thanks for clearing my comment. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since `new Date(2015,9,25)` is not valid JSON, than you need to use  [`eval(yourString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to parse your string to valid Object:

```js
console.log(eval('[{ date: new Date(2015,9,25), NAV: 12},{ date: new Date(2016,9,25), NAV: 22}]'));
```

Comment: 20 seconds to late :))

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to a valid Javascript object using function

```
JSON.parse(str);
```

but string should be in valid json format.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);

or 

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

may be this might help

Comment: What's the difference between two lines of code? When it's better to use first over second?

Comment: '$' and 'jQuery' both are same, except '$' is just an alias of 'jQuery'.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it to json.parse:

```
    var json = $.parseJSON(myString)
```

or you can refer this link below

[Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)